# How can I see all FE nine-patch bitmaps?

Tags: front-end, undocumented

The FE stores a bunch of little nine-patch images in the layout that govern the appearance of much of Mathematica. These things are incredibly useful to have as they may be used to give a clean appearance to custom `Panel` and `Button` objects and things.

How can I get these?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a little function that gets the `` FrontEnd`FileName `` stuff:

```
bmpPath =
  ToFileName /@
   DeleteCases[
    CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {PrivatePaths, "Bitmaps"}],
    ParentList
    ];(* use this if you want to look at _all_ of the bitmaps *)

bmpPath = 
  FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
    "SystemResources", "Bitmaps"};

feBMPs =
  AssociationMap[
   With[{key = #[[1]], groups = #[[2]]},
     key ->
      AssociationMap[
       #[[1]] ->
         With[{p = #[[1]]}, Association@

           Map[StringSplit[FileNameTake[#], "."][[1]] -> 
              FrontEnd`FileName[
               Evaluate@If[key === "Bitmaps", {p}, {key, p}], 
               Evaluate@FileNameTake[#]] &, #[[2]]]
          ] &,
       groups
       ]
     ] &,
   Map[
    GroupBy[#, FileNameTake[#, {-2}] &] &,
    GroupBy[
     FileNames["*.9.png", bmpPath, 
      5],
     FileNameTake[#, {-3}] &
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Then we can analyze some of this stuff:

```
feBMPs // Keys

{"Dialogs", "Choosers", "Popups", "Ribbons", "Bitmaps", "Toolbars", "Typeset"}

Keys /@ feBMPs

<|"Dialogs" -> {"CloudLogin", "Activation", "CloudDialogs", 
   "DeployCDF", "WelcomeScreen"}, "Choosers" -> {"Color"}, 
 "Popups" -> {"CodeCompletion"}, "Ribbons" -> {"Common", "Image"}, 
 "Bitmaps" -> {"Toolbars"}, "Toolbars" -> {"Player"}, 
 "Typeset" -> {"Audio", "FormObject", "InputField", "PrintTemporary", 
   "ProgressIndicator", "Quantity", "SummaryBox", "TableView"}|>
```

And we can look at some elements in the thing explicitly. Here are all the bitmaps used in the little autocompletion popup:

```
Map[
  RawBoxes@DynamicBox[FEPrivate`ImportImage[#]] &,
  feBMPs["Popups", "CodeCompletion"]
  ] // Dataset
```

[image]